# MQTT / Camel / Custom header parameters

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, mqtt

So, the problem:
i need to send some custom value in the header via Apache Camel/MQTT.

Code example:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class MQTTEntryPoint {

    private static final String BASE = "mqtt:test?host=tcp://ip_address&";
    private static final String SUBSCRIBER = BASE + "subscribeTopicName=test2";
    private static final String PUBLISHER = BASE + "publishTopicName=test2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message message = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate().receive(SUBSCRIBER).getIn();
                String body = message.getBody(String.class);
                System.out.println(body);
                Map<String, Object> headers = message.getHeaders();
                for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println("Header key: " + key + ", Header value: " + headers.get(key));
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        camelContext.createProducerTemplate().sendBodyAndHeader(PUBLISHER, "some body value", "headerKey",
                "some header value");

    }
}
```

In system out i can see only:

```
some body value
Header key: CamelMQTTSubscribeTopic, Header value: test2
```

As you can see, sending of custom header value does not works. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The MQTT protocol AFAIR only supports a single payload without any additional headers.

Comment: Thx for reply.
This also applies to `sendBodyAndProperty` method?

Comment: @AndrewSikorsky, Is there a transformation that can be done to include headers while in a camel route?